# Determining appropriate xpath selectors for elements in a custom context menu

Tags: html, xpath, contextmenu, web-inspector, browser-console

I'm trying to figure out the appropriate xpath selector to use for a particular option in a website's custom context menu. However, if I click to expand the context menu's HTML in the element inspector/dev console, to try and examine the elements within it... this causes the context menu itself to disappear.

Is there some kind of keyboard shortcut or alternative method I can use to inspect the elements of a custom context menu?